# Refer to parent object from child object without assigning an object literal to a variable

Tags: javascript

I need to refer to a parent object from a child object without using a variable assignment , something like the super keyword but in literal my example would be :

```
{ a:1,
  b:{e:a}
}
```

There is a solution which is

```
var obj = {
a: 1,
b: {
    get e() {
        return obj.a
    }
}
```

}
But I am asking if it is possible without assigning the object literal to a variable

Comment: No he is assigning the object to a variable here, I can't do that in my code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `this` to refer the same level object but in your case, it's nested so use nested getter to keep the parent context.

```js
var obj = {
  a: 1,
  get b() {
    const pctx = this;
    return {
      get e() {
        return pctx.a
      },
      c: 1
    }
  }
}

console.log(obj.b.e)
```

**Note:** This way the reference of the nested object will be different each time and you can't update the property of the nested object.

Comment: Thanks for the answer otherwise I don't need to update the nested object's property directly I need it as a read only right now but I could change its value by changing the 'a' variable values